# xml not showing checkbox prechecked

Tags: android, xml, checkbox

i have create an app in which,i want to show the checkbox prechecked with the help of xml,and after that user can checked or uncheked the checkbox,but xaml is not showing it checked on start of the app in device,what is the problem.please advise.

**MainActivity**

```
public class File_Selecter extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
     EditText edDelimiter, edqualifier, edcolumn, edrow;
    ListView list;
    StringBuilder addition = new StringBuilder();
    ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> list3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> phno0 = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Button btnsave;
    String str;
    int t;
    int count = 0;
    String[] BreakData, roz;
    TextView textnum;
    static String fileinfo;
    static StringBuilder conct = new StringBuilder();
    static int ResultCode = 12;
    String name = "", number = "";
    MyAdapter ma;
    String fin = "";
    String[] cellArray;
    String[] art = null;;
    String pathname = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath();
    static String contacts = "";
static String mixer;
static String delimiter, qulifier;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_file);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(
                Color.parseColor("#00aef0"));
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
        Intent itadd = new Intent();
        // edittext name
        // final String name=itadd.getStringExtra("name").toString();
        textnum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textnum1);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        ma = new MyAdapter();
        list.setAdapter(ma);
        // list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        // list.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        // list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        edDelimiter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edDelimiter);
        edcolumn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edcoloumns);
        edrow = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edrow);
        edqualifier = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edqualifier);
        // edittext number
        // final String number=itadd.getStringExtra("number").toString();

        edDelimiter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                edDelimiter.setError(null);
            }
        });
        if(fileinfo!=null){
        //Toast.makeText(getApplication(),
                //fileinfo.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                //.show();
        if (delimiter != null){
            edDelimiter.setText( SmsSend
                    .delim1.toString());

            qulifier= SmsSend
                    .qulifier.toString(); }
        ToRead(fileinfo);
        // contacts from smssend

        contacts = SmsSend.contacts1;

        if (SmsSend.contacts1 != null) {
            cellArray = contacts.split(";");
            if(list2.size() != 0){
            for (int i = 0; i < cellArray.length; i++) {

                for (int j = 0; j < list2.size(); j++) {
                    if (list2.get(j).contains(cellArray[i])) {
                        //ma.setChecked(j, true);

                        break;
                    }}}}
                else{
                    for (int i = 0; i < cellArray.length; i++) {

                        for (int j = 0; j < list1.size(); j++) {
                            if (list1.get(j).contains(cellArray[i])) {
                                //ma.setChecked(j, true);

                                break;  
                            }
                        }
                    }

        }
            }
        }
        // button1
        btnsave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsave);
        btnsave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(edDelimiter.getText().toString().length()== 0){
                    edDelimiter.setError("Delimiter ir required");
                } 
                if(File_Explorer.fileSizeInMB <= 1){
                ToRead(fileinfo);
//finish();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "file size is too large", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });


    }

    public void ToRead(String fileinfo) {

        if (fileinfo != null) {
             delimiter = edDelimiter.getText().toString();
            // Toast.makeText(getApplication(), delimiter, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//delim=":";
             qulifier = edqualifier.getText().toString();
             //Toast.makeText(getApplication(), qulifier.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // qulifier="\\";
            // finish();

             mixer = qulifier + delimiter;
            BreakData = fileinfo.split(mixer);

            str = edrow.getText().toString().trim();
            try {
                t = Integer.parseInt(str);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                // Handle parse error.
            }

            if (BreakData != null) {
                // String t2= (String.valueOf(t));
                if (File_Explorer.fileExtension.equals("vcf")) {

                    if (!(String.valueOf(t)).equals("0")) {

                        if (t > BreakData.length) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),
                                    "Data is less then entered rows",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Arrays.fill(BreakData, null);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),
                                    "empty.................", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        } else {

                            for (int i = 0; i < BreakData.length; i++) {
                                if (BreakData[i].contains("FN")) {
                                    art = BreakData[i + 1].split("\n");

                                    name = art[0].toString();

                                } else if (BreakData[i].contains("TEL;CELL")) {
                                    roz = BreakData[i + 1].split("\n");
                                    number = roz[0].toString();
                                    fin = name.toString() + "\n" + "\n"
                                            + number.toString();

                                    list2.add(fin.toString());

                                }
                            }
                            for (int a = 0; a < list2.size() && a < t; a++) {
                                list1.add(list2.get(a).toString());

                            }

                        }
                        textnum.setText(Integer.toString(list1.size()));

                    }

                    else {

                        for (int i = 0; i < BreakData.length; i++) {
                            if (BreakData[i].contains("FN")) {
                                art = BreakData[i + 1].split("\n");

                                name = art[0].toString();

                            } else if (BreakData[i].contains("TEL;CELL")) {
                                roz = BreakData[i + 1].split("\n");
                                number = roz[0].toString();
                                fin = name.toString() + "\n" + "\n"
                                        + number.toString();

                                list1.add(fin.toString());

                            }

                        }
                        textnum.setText(Integer.toString(list1.size()));
                    }

                } else {

                    if (!(String.valueOf(t)).equals("0")) {
                        if (t > BreakData.length) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),
                                    "Data is less then entered rows",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Arrays.fill(BreakData, null);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),
                                    "empty.................", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        } else {

                            for (int i = 0; i < BreakData.length && i < t; i++) {
                                list1.add(BreakData[i].toString());

                            }
                            textnum.setText(Integer.toString(t));
                        }
                    }

                    else {

                        for (int i = 0; i < BreakData.length; i++) {
                            list1.add(BreakData[i].toString());
                            //t = i;
                        }

                        textnum.setText(Integer.toString(BreakData.length));
                    }

                }
            }

        }

        list.setAdapter(ma);
        // fileinfo= null;
        //edDelimiter.setText(null);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        StringBuilder checkedcontacts = new StringBuilder();
        System.out.println(".............." + ma.mCheckStates.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++)

        {
            if (ma.mCheckStates.get(i) == false) {
                // Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "hiii",
                // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(list1.get(i)
                        .toString(), "\n");
                String first = st1.nextToken();
                String second = st1.nextToken();
                phno0.add(second.toString());
                checkedcontacts.append(list1.get(i).toString());
                checkedcontacts.append("\n");

            } else {
                System.out.println("..Not Checked......"
                        + list1.get(i).toString());
            }

        }
//Toast.makeText(getApplication(), phno0.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("extermal_name", phno0);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);

        finish();

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ma.toggle(arg2);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_button, menu);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.attachments:
            fileinfo = null;    
                Intent i = new Intent(File_Selecter.this, File_Explorer.class);

                startActivityForResult(i, ResultCode);

            break;
        case android.R.id.home:
            // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
            StringBuilder checkedcontacts = new StringBuilder();
            System.out.println(".............." + ma.mCheckStates.size());
            for (int j = 0; j < list1.size(); j++)

            {
                if (ma.mCheckStates.get(j) == true) {
                    StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(list1.get(j)
                            .toString(), "\n");
                    String first = st1.nextToken();
                    String second = st1.nextToken();
                    phno0.add(second.toString());
                    checkedcontacts.append(list1.get(j).toString());
                    checkedcontacts.append("\n");

                } else {
                    System.out.println("..Not Checked......"
                            + list1.get(j).toString());
                }

            }

            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            returnIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("extermal_name", phno0);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);

            finish();
            break;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == ResultCode) {

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                fileinfo = data.getStringExtra("name");

            }

            // list.setAdapter(ma);
        }

        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

        }

    }
```

**AdapterCLass**

```
    class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements
            CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
        public SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
        LayoutInflater mInflater;
        TextView tv1, tv;
        CheckBox cb;

        MyAdapter() {
            mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(list1.size());
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) File_Selecter.this
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        // Save ListView state

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return list1.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View vi = convertView;
            if (convertView == null)
                vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            tv = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            // tv1 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            cb = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            tv.setText(list1.get(position));
            // tv1.setText(phno1.get(position));
            cb.setTag(position);

            //cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, true));
            cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

            return vi;

        }

        public boolean isChecked(int position) {

            return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
        }

        public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
            mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);
              notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void toggle(int position) {
            setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);

        }
    }

}
```

**row.layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:ems="20"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#0082e6" />



    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:checked="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: close the xml file and reopen it and check..

Comment: remove this line **cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, true));**

Comment: @ Lal what will happen then..??

Comment: SparseBooleanArray is used for retrieving the values corresponding to chexked chexkbox

Comment: @ shayan pourvatan  i post my complete class code,you can see it now,execpt it i did not use sparseBooleanArray anywhere else.

Comment: @ shayan pourvatan i did not make any constructor of SpaseBooleanArray.,what all i did,i post that already,and i am new in android so just leaning things right now.

Comment: list1.size is the data that i m reading from the file,and i am passing it in sparseBooleanArray to get the position of the item,and i also post how i am getting list.size from file in post

Comment: @  kalyan pvs i did what you asked me to do..,but now its toggle is not working correctly,on uncheck the checkbox,it also retriveing its values